# sethostent(...) and endhostent() with NDK

Tags: android, networking, tcp, android-ndk

We are porting some code to NDK but it appears that sethostent(...) and endhostent() are infndefed in 'netdb.h'.

```
#if 0 /* MISSING FROM BIONIC */
...
void endhostent(void);
void sethostent(int);
...
#endif /* MISSING */
```

Aren't these functions needed for Android or there are any replacements?

Comment: Bionic libc is deliberately much smaller than gnu libc

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: No, it's under development yet. W'll come back to it later.